# Angular emit inside a promise not working

Tags: angular, eventemitter

In my Angular project I want to emit inside the .then and .catch, but they do net get called. Everything else inside the .then and .catch does get called.

When I emit outside the promise it does work.

**This is my code**

```js
updateAssignee(newAssignee: string) {
    this.storyService.updateAssignee(this.story, newAssignee).then(res =>{
      console.log('test')     //This one gets called
      this.onError.emit({     //This one does not get called
        error: false,
        errorText: ''
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('test')     //This one gets called
      this.onError.emit({     //This one does not get called
        error: true,
        errorText: '• ' + error.message
      });
    });

    this.onError.emit({     //This one gets called
      error: false,
      errorText: '• Missing permissions'
    });
  }
```

Is it not possible to emit inside the .then and .catch? Or am I missing something?

The way these components are loaded is via a ngFor loop. Maybe this causes some problems?

```js
<span *ngFor="let story of done">
    <app-storyboard-story (onError)="throwError($event)" [story]="story" [project]="project" cdkDrag></app-storyboard-story>
</span>
```

Comment: it is possible, how do you verify that it wasn't called?

Comment: By logging the results. The function where the emit is supposed to go does not get called. Only by the one outside the promise

Comment: perhaps the listener is unsubscribed by that time. try to add `this.onError.subscribe(console.log)`, before the `this.storyService` to ensure they aren't called.

Comment: Okay then they do get called

Comment: yep - it means the listener you want to notify is unsubscribed - so you need to change the way how it listens and how the flow goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on the code sample looks like `ngFor` detects changes and unsubscribes from the children components.

The solution would be to implement `trackBy` https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf, that should help to keep instances of children components when the `done` has been changed.

**ORIGINAL**

In the above above nothing is broken. You can verify that it works via adding

```js
this.onError.subscribe(console.log);
```

before `this.storyService` call.

I would suggest you to investigate how the listener subscribes and unsubscribes and change its flow because looks like it unsubscribes (call ngIf or something that removes the component from the render) too early.

With the provided code it's impossible to give you better advice.

Comment: I added some code on how these components get loaded, maybe this is helpful?

Comment: yeah, I'm quite sure that the `let story of done` has been changed before the call of `throwError`. Does `this.storyService.updateAssignee(this.story, newAssignee)` changes the `done` somehow?

Comment: I think it is because of the ngOnChanges on the parent. They reorder the stories after a change

Comment: yeah - try to use `trackBy` for the `ngFor` https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf